# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64 bit login loop

Tags: 14.04, login, lightdm

I have Ubuntu 14.04 LTS  64 bit. So I changed my password through recovery mode, and now it is in log-in loop.

Whenever I put `Xauthority` it says "No such file or directory"
When I put in my actual username, it says something like user not existing.

To fix the log-in loop issue, I tried

```
chown -R [user-name]:[user-name] /home[user]
```

when typing for user and user-name I typed in my actual user name. It says chwon: invalid user: '[*myusername*]:[*myusername*]' "

===
I tried `cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd` and just got a long list of things.

====
2.

```
sudo rm .Xauthority .XauthorityBak
```

`sudo reboot` 
it says "**rm: cannot stat '.Xauthority': No such file or directory** after the first tag

===
3.
    sudo rm/home//.Xauthority*

    `sudo apt-getinstall--reinstall xorg`

 `sudo reboot`

When I type in `.xsession-errors`, to see what could be wrong, it says command not found.

On another occasion, it did work, but it was before I changed the password through recovery mode.

Comment: Remember the name displayed on the GUI login screen is your *fullname* (or 'display name'): your actual system username will usually be the same as the name of your home directory e.g. `chown -R steeldriver:steeldriver /home/steeldriver`. Be especially careful about capitalization.

Comment: Also please try to be clear about what commands you actually typed: `rm/home//.Xauthority*` doesn't really make sense - did you mean `rm /home/user/.Xauthority*`? And what does 'do the `.xsession-errors`' mean?

Comment: 1. so if my display name has a space in it, is the space replaced by hypen?( - ) 2. yes thats what I meant rm

Comment: You should ignore the display name completely: you need to figure out your actual username, either based on the home directory name (not 100% guaranteed) or for example using `getent passwd 1000` for the user created at install time. An `.Xauthority` file will be created on your next successful session login: it doesn't matter if it's missing.

Comment: Yes you would replace both `user` and `user-name` with `adarren`. You don't need the `*`, just `rm /home/adarren/.Xauthority` should be sufficient

Comment: Are you literally adding brackets `[` and `]` ? if so - don't: just `chown -R adarren:adarren /home/adarren`

Comment: It suggests that file ownership is not the root cause of your issue: can you please run `tail /home/adarren/.xsession-errors` and [edit] your question to include the output please?

Comment: Sorry in that case I'm out of ideas

Comment: Sorry I really have no idea why anyone would suggest those modifications to your `/etc/X11/Xsession` file (it seems completely inappropriate to me)

Comment: What is the output of "cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd" Can we move this to
[chat]

Comment: yes please type in the output of this command and [edit] question

Comment: can you use root privileges?             sudo -i

Comment: @DnrDevil so I tried `cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd` I just got a long list of things. As for root privileges, no idea what that is. I assume I just type in `-i`

Comment: No I don't It says command not found.  I recently changed my password via recovery mode and now its a loop.

Comment: no type the full command

Comment: Seriously, it's like the 5th question about something dumb you've done. If you want a good advice, stop using the command line until you don't know how to do it. Don't change the systems settings, don't mess with the default. You'll soon get a broken system.

Comment: @DnrDevil what's the full command supposed to look like

Comment: @EduardoCola dude you were the one who told me to do it through recovery mode and it worked now but there's a login loop.

Comment: Recovery mode? I told you to use a Live media.

Comment: can you tell me what DnrDevil means? Or should I just uninstall ubuntu altogether.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried this:

```
 sudo nano /etc/X11/Xsession
```

and write this in:

```
 [Default]
 name=Xsession
 orge=/etc/X11/Xsession
```

And then enter this:

```
 sudo apt-get -install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get upgrade 
 sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

and it might work fine this way.

Comment: Isn't `/etc/X11/Xsession` supposed to be a shell script? What exactly is your rationale for the edits you are suggesting here?

Comment: @Noob my comment was directed to Michael

Comment: I know that just what does he mean I need to get this fixed today

Comment: Best answer I have might work

Comment: I concur @steeldriver, your edit makes no sense in a shell script! You either mean a different file or are just talking bullsh....